# Python 3.x - iloc throws error - "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"

Tags: python, indexing, dataframe, web-scraping

I am scraping election data from a website and trying to store it in a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4
import requests

columns = ['Candidate','Party','Criminal Cases','Education','Age','Total Assets','Liabilities']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

ind=1

url = requests.get("http://myneta.info/up2007/index.php?action=show_candidates&constituency_id=341")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.content)

for content in soup.findAll("td")[16:]:
    df.iloc[ind//7,ind%7-1] = content.text
    ind=ind+1
print(df)
```

Essentially, each iteration of content.text will provide me a value which I will populate in the table. The loop will populate values to df in the following sequence -

```
df[0,0]
df[0,1]
df[0,2]
.
.
.
df[1,0]
df[1,1]
.
.
```

and so on. Unfortunately the iloc is throwing an error - "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds". The funny part is when I try `df.iloc[0,0] = content.text` outside the for loop (in a separate cell for testing purpose), the code works properly, but in the for loop it creates an error. I believe it might be something trivial but i am unable to understand.Please help

Comment: Include the traceback when asking why a piece of code is not working, if you get any. `ind%7-1` will produce `-1` for 7, which is probably throwing you off. Also, is your example complete? `DataFrame.iloc` shouldn't even be able to append data (or I've missed something in your example).

Comment: @IljaEverilä i agree, but that will happen after the for loop has run 6 times. The issue is that it isnt running even once. I have a logic to handle 'ind =7', but to get to that logic , 'ind=1,2...' needs to run first

Comment: The issue still stands that using `iloc` you shouldn't be able to append to a `DataFrame`. Your `df` is initially empty.

Comment: Let me elucidate more simply. The problem ultimately boils down to something of this sort - 

'
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['a','b','c'])

df1.iloc[0,0]=1   - # Does not work
Output - single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

df1.loc[0,'a']=1   - # Works
print(df1)
Output   a    b    c
0  1  NaN  NaN'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Pandas version 0.17.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115270/discussion-between-rohan-bapat-and-ilja-everila).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`DataFrame.iloc` cannot enlarge its target object. This used to be the error message, but has changed since version 0.15.

In general a `DataFrame` is not meant to be built row at a time. It is very inefficient. Instead you should create a more traditional data structure and populate a `DataFrame` from it:

```
table = soup.find(id='table1')
rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:]
data = [[cell.text for cell in row.find_all('td')] for row in rows]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

From inspecting the page in your request it seems you were after the table with the id "table1", which has as the first row the header (a poor choice from the authors of that page, should've been in `<thead>`, not the body). So skip the first row (`[1:]`) and then build a list of lists from the cells of the rows.

Of course you could also just let pandas worry about parsing and all:

```
url = "http://myneta.info/up2007/index.php?action=show_candidates&constituency_id=341"
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[2]  # Pick the 3rd table in the page
```

Answer (score 0):

THis is a workaround.  I get the same iloc error with my pandas version.  This modified code overcomes it by creating a blank record (by creating a 1-row dataframe and appending to existing one) each iteration before assigning values to them.

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4
import requests

columns = ['Candidate','Party','Criminal Cases','Education','Age','Total Assets','Liabilities']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

ind=1
url = requests.get("http://myneta.info/up2007/index.php?action=show_candidates&constituency_id=341")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.content)

for content in soup.findAll("td")[16:]:
    data = pd.DataFrame({columns[0]:"",
                     columns[1]:"",
                     columns[2]:"",
                     columns[3]:"",
                     columns[4]:"",
                     columns[5]:"",
                     columns[6]:"",
                    },index=[0])
    df=df.append(data,,ignore_index=True)
    df.iloc[ind//7,ind%7-1] = content.text
    ind=ind+1
```

Comment: Please explain what was the issue and what you did to change it instead of just dumping the code. Thanks!