# python crawling error: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl data from website and generates an error as: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

The code is like below:

```
 headurl="https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/"
 endurl="?search_identifier=733971d356a1970075aa7789ec8c815c"
 midrul=""
 for i in range(0,len(data),1):
 midurl= data.iloc[i,1]
 midurl=str(midurl)
 web=headurl+midurl+endurl
 text=requests.get(web)

 try:
     address=re.compile(r'display_address: "(.*?)",\n')
     mytext1=re.findall(address,text.text)
     data.iloc[i,3]=mytext1[0]
 except:
     data.iloc[i,3]="nodata"
```

the mytext1 is actually existed as it would be printed out one by one when i use print()

Anyone knows why is the error generated?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `except` part of the code as I am sure you confirm by the error message. This has been answered before, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37960827/7176819.

Few tips:

- Include traceback when writing such questions
- Indent your code please.